# Newton's Laws of Motion - Question on Attwood's Machine

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

With regret I am unable to answer the following question.  Any assistance rendered would be very gratefully received

[image: page 1]

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: Is there any question .

Comment: Sincere apologies, I am new to this site.  A scan of the question text should now be accessible via a link

Comment: Hint: The whole system, which mass is $2M+m$ is pulled by the weight of the small rider, a force of magnitude $m g$. It remains to apply Newton's second law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, consider the movement from A to B:**

Newton's second law gives $$mg = (2M+m)a$$where $a$ is the acceleration from A to B. 
So we get $$a=\frac{mg}{2M+m}.$$
Besides, $v=at_{AB}$ and $h=\frac{1}{2}at_{AB}^2$ gives $v=\sqrt{2ah}$, where $v$ is the speed at B.

**Secondly, consider the movement from B to C:**
$$vt=h$$
Put in $v=\sqrt{2ah}$, after some simple algebra, you can get
$$g=\frac{h(2M+m)}{2mt^2}$$